# How to read packet saved in a file with Python?

Tags: python, packet-capture

I have a C++ code that generates an IP Packet Header. The code use a struct representing each field in the packet:

```
struct cip {
   uint8_t        ip_hl:4, /* both fields are 4 bytes */
                  ip_v:4;
   uint8_t        ip_tos;
   uint16_t       ip_len;
   uint16_t       ip_id;
   uint16_t       ip_off;
   uint8_t        ip_ttl;
   uint8_t        ip_p;
   uint16_t       ip_sum;
   struct in_addr ip_src;
   struct in_addr ip_dst;
   char       head[100];
};
```

The user is prompt an input message to enter the values for each variable  in the struct:

> Enter the filename to save the packet: packet
>
> Enter IP version(0-15): 4
>
> Enter Header Length(5-15): 5
>
> Enter type of service(0-255): 55
>
> Enter packet total size(bytes, 20, 200): 25

The packet is created and saved in a file:

```
FILE* f = fopen(file, "w");
int success = fwrite(&packet, sizeof(char), ((unsigned int)packet.ip_hl)*4,f);
if(success <= 0) {
    printf("Error writing packet header");
}
success = fwrite(&data, sizeof(char),ntohs(packet.ip_len)-(4*packet.ip_hl),f);
if(success < 0) {
    printf("Error writing packet data");
}
fflush(f);
fclose(f);
printf("\nPacket Written.\n");
```

I didn't create this code, someone gave me the code so I can create other program in Python that will validate the packet created by the program above. The validation includes verifying the checksum generated for the packet, the version of the Ip Packet, protocol, length of header and so on.

So I will like to know if someone can help me figuring out how can I read the file and parse the frame. I tried to read the line in the file as a string, but the problem I'm having is that the file looks like this after the creation: (it is unreadable)

> O  È ,@ šÀ¨À¨
>   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxDATA_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_****DATA****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__** ô·

I don't understand why: (I'm guessing that this is because the variables bigger than 1 byte are converted to big endian by the function "htons":

```
printf("\nEnter ip ID number(0-65535):\n");
scanf("%d", &input);
packet.ip_id = htons(input);
```

I tried to search for another option as dealing this with socket.makefile(), but this will help me the socket in my program as a file, but what I need to do is parse the frame gave to me in this file.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

P.S.: Also can someone give me a link where I can find how to convert integer from big endian to small endian and vicerversa in Python. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read file as usual (specifying "binary" mode for Windows):

```
with open("test.txt", 'br') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        # process lines
```

To unpack binary data you should use [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) package, which can also handle [big and little endian](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) and so on.  Example for your struct:

```
print struct.unpack('BBHHHBBH100s', line)
```

I omitted `ip_src` and `ip_dst` unpacking since you didn't specify the contents of their struct.  The least possible value to read is one byte, so to split first field into two parts you can use:

```
(ip_hl, ip_v) = (value >> 4, value & 15)
```

Of course, the order of 8-bit component depends on your struct endianess.

Comment: Thank you Denis. The structure for IP address is a structure in the libraries of C++, I'm guessing stdio.h.Also, some fields of the packet where converted from little to big endian (not all of them), it will affect if I apply little endian to all the packet?

Comment: You can have only one endianess per unpacking.  However it's possible to re-unpack specific fields from one endianess to another, or just unpack the line by parts:  first with one endianess, then use `line[:offset]` to unpack the rest.

Comment: Denis, I'm confuse. You are referring to bytes in your example, but what I understand is that a data type uint16_t is 16 bits not 16 bytes, or Am I wrong? (Please correct me if I am) If I'm right, should I use the unsigned char to unpack my uint8_t fields and unsigned short for uint16_t?

Comment: Wait, your comment for `uint8_t` states it consists of two 4-bytes fields.

Comment: Sorry, not my comment, this is not my code. I researched and says that the ip_hl:4 field is 4 bits (because of the ":4"). So I have the problem now of unpacking bits not bytes.

Comment: Can I use B (1 byte) even thought the data is 4 bits? Wouldn't be taking part of the next field data? I have this code: print struct.unpack('@B', line[0:8]) #ip_hl, ip_v. Can I do this in each part of the line to apply the correct endianess?

Comment: It will, that's why I added a code to split this byte in halves.

Comment: Denis, it seems struct.unpack('@B', line[0:8]) does not work, other ideas to endianess conversion per field?

Comment: `line[0:8]` returns 8 bytes, you need only 1.  Use `line[0]`.

Comment: So, this is how we have the code: var0 = struct.unpack('@B', line[0]) #ip_hl, ip_v
            (ip_hl, ip_v) = (var0 >> 4, var0 & 15)
             var1 = struct.unpack('<B', line[1]) #ip_tos
             var2 = struct.unpack('<H', line[2:4])#ip_len
             var3 =struct.unpack('<H', line[4:6])#ip_id
             var4 = struct.unpack('<H', line[6:8])#ip_off
             ... var11 = struct.unpack('s', line[20:])#head, data

Comment: Still with the error "struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 1"

Comment: You should specify string length, like I did in example: `var11 = struct.unpack('100s', line[20:])`.